# How to fix error 'Cannot lock buildSrc build lock as it has already been locked by this process.' with Gradle 5 and GradleBuild tasks

Tags: gradle

We have a gradle build which dynamically create several  tasks of GradleBuild type to run with different client library versions to test its compatibility. That worked fine with Gradle4 but after moving to Gradle5 I'm getting `Cannot lock buildSrc build lock as it has already been locked by this process.` error after execution of first of this tasks. So directory is locked by first build and is not released. Could you please advice how this can be fixed?
It is like this

```
task testAll {
    dependsOn  clientVersions.collect { "runTestsWithClient$it" }
    clientVersions.forEach { version ->
        task "runTestsWithClient$version"(type: GradleBuild) {
            buildFile = "build.gradle"
            tasks = ["testClient"]
            startParameter.projectProperties = [clientVersion: version]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Just wondering: why do you need a separate Gradle build for each test task run? Why not simply create different variants of the `testClient` task and run those?

Comment: Because number and versions of of client lib to test is dynamic and parsed from external source. So it is not possible to have static tasks. Also each task in example uses dependency of particular version :(

Comment: Hmm, not sure if I understand what you mean by "each task in example uses dependency of particular version". Could you perhaps show what `testClient` does?

Comment: Nothing special, it executes tests from a class:

```
task testClient(type: Test) {
    filter {
        includeTestsMatching "*.ClientCompatibilityTest"
    }   
}
```

The trick is that parameter is set to particular dependency version 

`startParameter.projectProperties = [clientVersion: version]`

and dependency is like


 `testCompile group: "xxxxx", name: "client-all", version: project.clientVersion`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend to not run these tests in separate `GradleBuild` tasks. I would rather try to set up a local `Test` task for each test from a shared task template; these `Test` tasks will then only differ in the test classpath.

To make sure that the different client version dependencies won’t interfere, I would generate separate configurations for each of them and add the dependencies on these.

Here’s a basic example that should work with Gradle 5.6.1 (and probably earlier):

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
}

repositories {
    ivy {
        url = 'file:///tmp/my-repo'
    }
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
}

def clientVersions = [1, 2, 3]

task('testAll')

clientVersions.each { v ->
    def configName = "myConfig$v"
    def config = configurations.create(configName)
    dependencies.add(configName, "com.example:foo:$v")

    def taskName = "testClient$v"
    task(taskName, type: Test) {
        classpath += config
        // TODO use other shared test configuration such as:
        // filter { includeTestsMatching "*.ClientCompatibilityTest" }
    }
    testAll.dependsOn taskName
}
```

Let me know if you have any questions on how this works.

Comment: thanks it looks elegant! Refactored t that way but for now getting error on compilation task that classes from my dependency are unresolved reference. Checked classpath of the tasks `println(classpath.asFileTree.files)`  and it does contain correct jar version and file exists on filesystem. Trying to debug

Comment: It looks like `classpath += config` adds deps but this classpath is not applied on the compile step

Comment: Ah sorry, it was IDE problem after moving to gradle5, continue fixing

Comment: No, unfortunately can't make it work for now, it seems like classes from dependency can't be found and it is compilation error. May be you have ideas why jar is in this classpath but they are not found? Thanks in advance

Comment: In the debug log I can see that dependency is filtered for some reason

17:14:06.912 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.graph.builder.DependencyGraphBuilder] Visiting configuration client-compatibility-tests:dev.0(myConfig2019.1.11683).
17:14:06.913 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.graph.builder.DependencyGraphBuilder] dependency: client-all:2019.1.11683 from-conf: myConfig2019.1.11683 to-conf: null is filtered.

Not understand why it is filtered

Comment: At last solved this. It was necessary not only add config to dependencies of test task as classpath as it only runtime. But also I have to add  client dependency to testCompileOnly config to have this classes on compilation. So in runtime there is particular version of client libs and fixed on on stage of compilation

`testCompileOnly group: "xxxx", name: "client", version: "xxx"`